# Changing the name of the file to folder name

Tags: python, os.walk

I have some files and I want to change names to their folder names. However, the problem is that sometimes they are located in main folder and sometimes in subfolders.
For instance lets assume that "Es" is the main directory
Then I have three options:

```
Es--> France---_-2011 --> import.csv
Es--> Italy---_-2012 --> files --> import.csv
Es -->France---_-2012 --> files --> recent --> import.csv
```

And my desired outputs are: France---*-2011.csv for the first one, Italy---*-2012.csv for the second and France---_-2012.csv for the third one

I have something like this:

```
# Core settings

rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\es\\den'
extension = ".zip"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if not root.endswith(extension):
        new_list = []
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".csv"):
                os.chdir(root)
                print(root)
                add_id = root.split("---_-")[1]
                add_id = add_id.split("\\")[0]
                print(add_id)
```

How I could do that ?

Comment: Can you show your actual folder structure and how do you want your files renamed precisely as it's unclear from your question.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Join path ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join))

```
full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
# C:\\Users\\Es\\France-----2011\\import.csv
```

#### Get relative path ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath))

```
rel_path = os.path.relpath(full_path, rootdir)
# France-----2011\\import.csv
```

#### Split **THE** directory ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep))

```
the_dir_name = rel_path.split(os.sep)[0]
# France-----2011
```

#### Rename ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename))

```
new_filename = the_dir_name + ".csv"
os.rename(full_path, os.path.join(root, new_filename))
# rename C:\\Users\\Es\\France-----2011\\import.csv 
# to     C:\\Users\\Es\\France-----2011\\France-----2011.csv
```